# Tradingview Pine script alert message not working

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, alerts, pine-script-v4

first of all i dont know much about coding so keep that in mind. :)

I created a strategy in Tradingview and i would like to create an alert for it that displays a specific message for Capitalize AI to trigger buy/sell or close positions.

for example for capitalize ai a webhook message looks like something like this :

```
{"alertId": "e351d512-ffc7-40ac-af940-661eb8af2e43"}
```

The message has to look like exactly like this otherwise capitalize ai wont recognize it.

So my problem is this.

for example if i write the strategy. entry like this:

```
strategy.entry(id="Buy", long=true, when=enterLong(), alert_message = "Hello Everybod")
```

When the strategy "buys" the alert message will display Hello Everybody,

But if i insert the webhook message in Pine Script like this :

```
strategy.entry(id="Buy", long=true, when=enterLong(), alert_message = "{"alertId": "e351d512-ffc7-40ac-af940-661eb8af2e43"}")
```

the alert for the strategy should display the webhook message, but i guess because of the brackets inside the message the whole strategy script is just not working anymore and it displays an error message :

> line 176: required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'b'

My question is, is there some way to get it to work?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
strategy.entry(id="Buy", long=true, when=enterLong(), alert_message = '{"alertId": "e351d512-ffc7-40ac-af940-661eb8af2e43"}')
```